NewPage.aspx redirects to recycle bin on SavePage - suspected document library error
When I create a new page in SharePoint and save the page it automatically gets checked out and is moved to the recycle bin with the error
{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientServiceException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."}}}.
I suspect it has to do with an attempt to redirect news posts (pages) to a subfolder in SitePages being SitePages/News but as I failed to set it up correctly I reverted back to the default set-up.
I have removed the SitePages/News folder but every time I create a new page, the folder is added and the new page ends up in the recycle bin looking like this:
screenshot of the recycle bin]1
